# cygwin tar omits directory when creating archive

Tags: cygwin, tar

I have the following directory structure

```
books/java
books/java.ebooks
books/java.gwt
books/java.swing
books/javaee
```

I use this command to create an archive of all the directories starting with the letters a-m

```
tar czf books.a-m.no.AI.tgz --exclude=books/AI.and.algorithms --exclude=books/[N-Z]* --exclude=books/[n-z]* books
```

The .tgz archive that gets created does not contain the java.swing/ directory.

Am I missing something in my use of tar or is this a bug in cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the java.swing/ directory is empty.  Apparently cygwin tar silently omits empty directories.  There is nothing in the --help about empty directories either.